# Pointwise limit of seq.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, sequence-of-function

$(f_n)_(n\geq2)$

$$f_n (x) =
 \begin{cases}
  1-n^2x &\quad\text{for}\quad x \in [0,\frac{1}{n^2}]\\
  0 &\quad\text{for}\quad x \in (\frac{1}{n^2},\frac{2}{n^2}) \\
  x - \frac{2}{n^2} &\quad\text{for}\quad x \in [\frac{2}{n^2},1].
 \end{cases} $$

We just need to find the pointwise limit and i'm a little stuck.

I know that for $x=0$ we can do $f_n(0) = 1$ and hence $lim$ here is 1

But then I want to fix x between $0,1$ would i do this in separate cases. One between $(0,\frac{1}{n^2})$  and $[\frac{1}{n^2},1]$

I'm kind of stuck if anyone could show a working to this, it'd be really helpful

Comment: Welcome to MSE! As a more geometric way of understanding the problem, a good first idea is to [graph these functions](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/6vek9v7j3x) (say for $n < 100$). This will make clear what you _want_ the answer to be, which can help guide your algebraic manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x>0$, then $\frac2{n^2}<x$ if $n\gg1$ and then you have $f_n(x)=x-\frac2{n^2}$. Since $\lim_{n\to\infty} x-\frac2{n^2}=x$, you have $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=x$.

Comment: Very much appreciated